# Interactive Checkbox in Latex

Tags: checkbox, latex, overleaf

Does anyone know how to do an interactive checkbox in LaTeX that can be **crossed** when it is clicked? Right now I can get it to work with with a checkbox that glows red when checked like this:

[image]

with

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \CheckBox[name=mycheckbox]{This is a check box:}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

but I'm not sure how you make it a cross instead of a glow when checked

Answer (score 6):

In theory you can use the `checkboxsymbol` option to choose which symbol from pifont you want to use - but be aware that not all pdf viewer will display this correctly. The following screenshot was taken with adobe reader.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \CheckBox[name=mycheckbox,checkboxsymbol=\ding{53}]{This is a check box:}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Mac preview will show the default checkmark instead, other viewers might show nothing at all.

Comment: yeah this doesn't seem to work on chrome :(

Comment: @Andrew Not surprised, chrome probably uses something based on pdf toolkit? With such things, adobe is usually the safe bet