# Interactive Checkbox in Latex with strike-through

Tags: latex, interactive

I would like to make a PDF to-do list similar to this one:
[Interactive Checkbox in Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472419/interactive-checkbox-in-latex)

With a few improvements. I would prefer the box on the left and the text on the right, and I would like to strike through (maybe changing the color) the ticked tasks, similarly to this Excel example:
[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this? For example, using different styles for activated links and activating/deactivating them by the checkbox?

Many thanks in anticipation,